# Is my batch accumulation implementation correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I’d like to know if my code for training a model with batch accumulation is correct. Especially the part regarding the loss calculation because I’m not so sure this is the right way to do this.
Here’s my code:

```
def train (start_epochs, n_epochs, best_acc, train_generator, val_generator, model, optimizer, criterion, checkpoint_path, best_model_path):


#num_epochs = 25
  since = time.time()

  #best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
  #best_acc = 0.0
  train_loss = []
  val_loss = []
  train_acc = []
  val_acc = []

  batch_accumulation = 8

  for epoch in tqdm(range(start_epochs, n_epochs+1)):

    running_train_loss = 0.0
    running_val_loss = 0.0

    running_train_corrects = 0
    running_val_corrects = 0

    optimizer.zero_grad
    #Training
    model.train()
    for i, (faces, labels) in tqdm(enumerate(train_generator)):
      
      faces = faces.to(device)
      labels = labels.to(device)

      #forward
      outputs = model(faces)

      #predictions of the model determined using the torch.max() function, which returns the index of the maximum value in a tensor.
      _, preds = torch.max(outputs[1], 1)

      #pass the model outputs and the true image labels to the loss function
      loss = criterion(outputs[1], labels)
      #loss = loss / batch_accumulation
      running_train_loss += loss.item()
      # Backprop and Adam optimisation
      loss.backward()
      # Track the accuracy and loss
      running_train_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

      if (i+1)% batch_accumulation == 0:
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad # zero the gradient buffers 
       
    # calculate average losses and accuracy  
    epoch_train_loss = running_train_loss / len(train_generator.dataset)
    epoch_train_acc = ((running_train_corrects.double() / len(train_generator.dataset)) * 100)
    train_loss.append(epoch_train_loss)
    train_acc.append(epoch_train_acc)

    print('Train Loss: {:.4f} Train Acc: {:.2f}%'.format(epoch_train_loss, epoch_train_acc))

    #Validation
    with torch.set_grad_enabled(False):
      model.eval()
      for i , (faces_val, labels_val) in tqdm(enumerate(val_generator)):

        faces_val = faces_val.to(device)
        labels_val = labels_val.to(device)
        
        if (i+1)% batch_accumulation == 0:

          outputs_val = model(faces_val)

          _, preds_val = torch.max(outputs_val[1], 1)
          loss_val = criterion(outputs_val[1], labels_val)

          running_val_loss += loss_val.item() 
          #running_val_loss = running_val_loss +((1 /(i+1)) * (loss.item() - running_val_loss))
          running_val_corrects += torch.sum(preds_val == labels_val.data)

    # calculate average losses and accuracy 
    epoch_val_loss = running_val_loss / len(validation_generator.dataset)
    epoch_val_acc = (running_val_corrects.double() / len(validation_generator.dataset)) * 100
    val_loss.append(epoch_val_loss)
    val_acc.append(epoch_val_acc)

    print('Validation Loss: {:.4f} Validation Acc: {:.2f}%'.format(epoch_val_loss, epoch_val_acc))
```

I got strange epoch train results (like 456.890) and I’m note sure about the if statement in the validation part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `gradient accumulation` (actual term) during validation phase, so this part over there:

```
if (i+1)% batch_accumulation == 0:    
    outputs_val = model(faces_val)
```

does not make any sense (no need for `if`). This technique is used solely for training to make the gradient estimation more accurate for small batches, hence we should focus on it.

### Gradient accumulation

Each time we run `backward()` calculated gradients are added to the leafs of the graph. Usually, we use `mean` across whole batch (divide the sum by number of elements in batch). Here, we accumulate the loss, hence we should divide it by the number of accumulation steps, which gives us (actually you had it commented out):

```
loss = criterion(outputs[1], labels)
loss = loss / batch_accumulation
```

Otherwise loss might be too big (probably the case here) and make the network unstable even with really small learning rates).

You may also run this:

```
running_train_loss += loss.item()
```

On a per-accumulation basis.

And lastly, as pointed out by [@Dishin H Goyani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63881404/10886420) `zero_grad` is a function so you should run:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Comment: I modified the code like you suggested! Now it seems to work. One more question: how about the dimensions of the batch size concerning the validation and the train set? I set both of them to 32, with an accumulation step = 8. Did I do correctly or should I set the validation set batch to 32*8 = 256?

Comment: Batch accumulation is not part of validation. You can push one example through network during validation or 1024. Batch accumulation is about loss during training and about updating parameters. So do validation as per normal, without gradient accumulation at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may missing parenthesis

```
optimizer.zero_grad # zero the gradient buffers
```

Right way to call is

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
```